# PHP curl_setopt() error invalid characters

Tags: php, curl

I have some code of a website in which cURL is used (not quite "mine"..part of an open source project) and after loading up the site on localhost of my VM for the first time in months because I want to help with a recent issue that has arisen, which is unrelated to cURL, I had fixed one local problem which was obvious to me and now when trying to log in to the site I get this error

```
curl_setopt(): Curl option contains invalid characters (\0)
```

Whatever I have messed up though, this seems to happen trying to load any page not just login page.
This is the line of code it points to

```
curl_setopt($re, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "slim_session=".$_COOKIE['slim_session'].";");
```

If it helps, through `error_log()`'ing I found that the value of `$_COOKIE['slim_session']` is `a:4:{s:10:"slim.flash";a:0:{}s:11:"AccessToken";O:48:"SolasMatch\\Common\\Protobufs\\Models\\OAuthResponse":4:{s:8:"`

Unfortunately cURL is not my strong suit, but I can provide more info on the situation as needed. You can see the full function the above code is from [here](https://github.com/TheRosettaFoundation/SOLAS-Match/blob/develop/Common/lib/APIHelper.class.php#L84).

Comment: Yes, the cookie does contain the nul byte (after s:8:). You need some code that checks and sanitizes the cookie before passing it to CURL.

Comment: You shouldn't serialise objects that way, because the private and protected properties have a null character in their name.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this code could have worked before or on different machines and such? Is there something that happened in a rather recent update to PHP or cURL?
Just FYI, my VM is on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS while the machines I would have worked on before in the place I had work placement in where the site was devved are on some version of 12.04 LTS, so maybe due to that PHP versions and such could be different..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that protected properties are serialised in a special way, i.e.:

```
s:14:"\000*\000_descriptor";N
```

And those null characters are disallowed when setting cURL options as part of the changes made due to [this security issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68089).

Passing serialised objects in this manner is risky, unless the values are either coming from a trusted source or bear a tamper proof signature. You may be able to make it work by first URL encoding the serialised value.

```
curl_setopt($re, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "slim_session=" . urlencode($_COOKIE['slim_session']) . ";");
```